# Line Integral - Newton's Law

Tags: integration, line-integrals

Newton's law of gravitation says that the intensity of the gravitational force between two objects with masses M is given by the following expression:

|F| = mMG / r²

R is the distance between objects and G is the gravitational constant (This is an example of an inverse square root law.) Let us suppose that an object with mass M is located at the origin of a vector field in R³. can be the mass of the earth and the origin would be at its center.) A position vector of the object acts towards the origin and the vector field in which the unit vector acts in its direction will be given by the equation **F(x,y,z) = x²yz + xy²z + xyz²**.

*Find the  **div F**, which represents the speed and direction of this gravitational field.*

Should I start with the speed of the gravitational field? Can someone help me? I have difficult to understand questions with text. But I'm searching and trying.

Comment: Help you with what? I don’t see a question anywhere in there that you’re trying to answer.

Comment: see the edit. thanks

Comment: maybe the grad(F)?

Comment: yeah.speed and direction

Comment: Some help with English - write 'strength of gravitational force' and 'intensity of gravitational field'. This is an example of an 'inverse square law' not an "inverse square root law". I am not sure what you mean by "speed of gravitational field", as what is normally calculated is the 'acceleration due to the gravitational field' or the 'force due to gravity', or the 'gravitational field potential' when working in terms of energy. Can you define exactly what x, y and z represent? and exactly what you are trying to calculate with the F(x,y,z) formula?

Comment: VTC as "unclear what you're asking" couldn't be more apt.